# October CMS : Create one article / page for every user

Tags: laravel-5, content-management-system, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-widgets

For a project I'm working on, I need customers to be able to create an account on a website (using Laravel if possible) and to be able to create one page for them with few easy steps to present their company.

Best would be to have a platform with content management, users management, roles and permissions.

I was wondering if this is possible to reach with October CMS, or is there a Laravel alternative to reach that goal ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest it will be best to go with october as its provides all the plugins you required and easy interface to add content.

happy coding.

### To solve Dashboard for each user (we assume you want this in backend):

- You will have one Super admin
- Now create your Plugin define some permission what you needed for different groups
- Then create group with set of permissions ( as per your need for your plugin)
- Then Create user with this groups and this user will have own there space based on group
- Ex. in one group you set permission to edit item - he can edit item
  with group which do not have permission that user will not allow to edit that item.

for reference you can check out this vide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbw0vkq4dnk

October Back-end users doc :
https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/users

Still having any issue please let me know.

### if you want dashboard at frontend side then flow looks like this

- i guess that would be possible to handle by only plugin :)
- just add users plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-user
- then process will be same as backend user you need to add user-groups
  then at registration time you can assign them groups
- Then with in plugin you can define restrictions (logged in / with different groups etc ..)
- so you need to add the user plugin read, its doc then craft your plugin based on roles and restrictions

Comment: Hey Hardik. Thanks for your answer. The whole part I'm not sure to understand is : how is it possible to have one "dashboard" for each users ? Is there something like this existing ? Like a SAAS boostrap application for OctoberCMS or will I have to code it myself ?

Comment: hmm that would be difficult.
- you can create multiple backend user then assign then different roles
- create plugin for backend and put dashboard there based on current logged in user

Comment: some times ago this plugin : https://octobercms.com/plugin/renatio-backupmanager was providing demo of its functinality by doing same thig it was creating _demo user_ dynamically and let it login pragmatically and show its plugin. so i guess that is doing same thing i guess

Comment: Hey Hardik ! 
Thanks a lot for your answer and thanks a lot for all the links.

Sorry my message was not clear enough. 

For dashboard backend, I was not making reference to this, sorry if I was not clear enough. 

On the website I'll have visitors who can create an account and hire a customer. 
Customer will be able to have a small backend on their side communicating with visitors. It's not the backend of the whole CMS. 

So is it possible with OctoberCMS to create "dashboards" between users ?
Thanks a lot for all your answers this is really helping !